# manage "errors" in string.toLowerCase() with special characters like "Ñ" or "É"

Tags: string, special-characters, translate, string-matching

I'm trying to do a translator in Java
I manage the dictionaries in binary trees but when I try to manage translate dictionaries like English-Spanish or viceversa words like "spanish" translate to "español". The problem I have is that I have to do a non case sensitive translate.
For this purpose I choose the string.toLowerCase() method but it deletes especial characters like "Ñ", "ñ" or accent words like "é". I compare the strings later on like this

```
str.toLowerCase(new Locale("es", "ES")).equals(dictionaryword.toLowerCase(new Locale("es", "ES")
```

That piece of code doesn't return true if for example

```
str = Español;
dictionaryword = español;
```

My question is if someone knows how to manage this "error" or if I'm doing something wrong.
Also, I don't know if I should try with

```
str.equalsIgnoreCase(dictionaryword)
```

instead of the toLowerCase(Locale) I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

If your `toLowerCase(locale)` function isn't working, I'd seriously suggest to implement it yourself. Since it's Spanish we are talking about, there is only a few special characters you should take care of.

Comment: The problem is that it should work for any language not only Spanish. But thanks, I'll have it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RegexReplace and StringReplace.

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "Ñ", "ñ");
str = Regex.Replace(str, "[A-Z]", "[a-z]");
```